# Get Conditionally Latest record from each group - without Aggregate functions or Partition

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have been trying to do this in many ways suggested.

**Note:** we do not want aggregate function or Partition since this is just a small part of whole Stored procedure and this is client requirement to not have it, so not in option and not possible duplicate of other existing answers / questions

I have a messages table, which has a column `from` and `to`, a foreign key to the user table, basically which user sends to whom at simplest. I also have other columns which are isSnoozed and snoozeAt for if the message is snoozed.

So the ordering is according to case. If messages is snoozed then consider snoozeAt time to Order or if not then consider sendAt. (right now we can ignore this condition while ordering, But I mentioned this since we **cannot take simply** `MAX(id)` )

I need to get recent most message from messages group by from user id
messages table like :

```
id -- to -- from -- isSnoozed -- snoozedAt -- sendAt ...
```

What I tried :

```
select * from ( select * from messages order by sendAt DESC) as TEMP GROUP BY TEMP.from
```

I tried many similar approaches but none worked.
I wasted many paid hours but can't find an approach which meets my exact requirement

**NOTE:** Please ignore typo in query if any, since I cant type in exact query table and names, So i typed in directly here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out by doing something like this, which could be explained in a simplified way:

```
select * from message where message.id in ( 
    select 
        ( select id from message where message.from = user.id order by CASE isSnoozed WHEN 0 THEN sendAt ELSE snoozeAt END DESC limit 1) as id
    from user where user.id in ( select friends.`whoIsAdded` from friends where friends.`whoAdded` = myId)
 ) order by CASE isSnoozed WHEN 0 THEN sendAt ELSE snoozeAt END DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you just want the largest value in one of two columns.  Assuming the values are never `NULL`, you can use `greatest()`:

```
select m.*
from messages m
where greatest(m.sendAt, m.snoozedAt) =
          (select max(greatest(m2.sendAt, m2.snoozedAt))
           from messages m2
           where m2.from = m.from
          );
```

If the columns can be `NULL`, then you can use `coalesce()` to give them more reasonable values.

Comment: I can get null values, but thats not the issue, we need to take it when isSnoozed it true, there is a state when snoozeAt is there but isSnoozed is 0, basically when the message is in between coming up. Also i tried this query gives incorrect result